# How to make the "what" ARG in find read data from a cell

Tags: vba, find, offset

I am trying to fill a table with Input boxes with respect to date.

I am using the find and offset function to determine location through VBA but I want the "WHAT" to find to be dependent on date I put in a cell.

See my code below.

```
Public userMsg As String, Rng As Range

Private Sub Button1_Click()

Dim Data_Cell As Variant
userMsg = InputBox("How many brews were mashed?", "No of brews", "Enter your value here", 500, 700)
Data_Cell = Range("B2").Value

Set Rng = Sheet2.Range("A3:A34").Find(What:=Data_Cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
 If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Captured"
        Rng.Offset(0, 1) = userMsg
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: So, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: You seem to have already solved your issue, or you misexplained it, because your code will look for the content of B2 in your worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, my source cell was a list from data validation, i used active x controls to do my list and it worked.